# Trouble with Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to get my table on the locations table on the locations page to fit inside its parent element when it is below 480px. My media query in my css checks for 250px - 780px but for some reason below 480 it starts to go off screen, and outside of its parent element. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Site: http://www.okatod.org

Here is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>OKATOD</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- My Work Machine -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\fitzst\Desktop\OKATOD\CSS2\locationsTheme.css" type="text/css" /> -->

        <!-- My Personal Pc -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="G:\OKATOD\Better OKATOD Website\CSS2\locationsTheme.css" type="text/css" /> -->

        <!-- Server -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS2/locationsTheme.css" type="text/css" />
        <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;" />

    </head>


    <body class="body">

        <header class="mainHeader">
            <img src="img/logo.gif">
            <nav><ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.okatod.org/index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="http://www.okatod.org/Locations.html">Locations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul></nav>
        </header>

        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="content">   
                    <article class="topcontent">    
                        <header>
                            <h2><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to this POST TITLE">OKATOD Locations</a></h2>
                        </header>

                        <table class="locationsTable">
                            <tr class="tableHeadings">
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Street Address</th>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                                <th>Zip Code</th>
                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Behavorial Health Group</td>
                                <td>5401 SW 29th</td>
                                <td>Oklahoma</td>
                                <td>OK</td>
                                <td>73128</td>
                                <td>(405)-681-2003</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Southern Oklahoma Treatment Services</td>
                                <td>905 Holiday Dr.</td>
                                <td>Ardmore</td>
                                <td>OK</td>
                                <td>73401</td>
                                <td>(580)-745-9083</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Southern Oklahoma Treatment Services</td>
                                <td>5912 US Hwy 70</td>
                                <td>Mead</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>73449</td>
                                <td>(580)-942-7650</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Rightway Medical</td>
                                <td>9017 South I-35 Service Road</td>
                                <td>Oklahoma City</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>73160</td>
                                <td>(405)-616-3366</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Quapaw Counseling Servies</td>
                                <td>58150 East 66 Road</td>
                                <td>Miami</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>74354</td>
                                <td>(918)-542-1786</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Rightway Medical of Bartlesville</td>
                                <td>610 W. Hensley Blvd</td>
                                <td>Bartlesville</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>74003</td>
                                <td>(918)-337-6007</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Rightway Medical of Roland</td>
                                <td>117 E. Ray Fine Blvd</td>
                                <td>Bartlesville</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>74954</td>
                                <td>(918)-427-3344</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Tulsa Rightway Medical</td>
                                <td>3445 S Sheridan Road E</td>
                                <td>Tulsa</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>74145</td>
                                <td>(918)-610-3366</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Oklahoma City Veterans Administration Medical</td>
                                <td>921 Northeast 13th St.</td>
                                <td>Oklahoma City</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>73104</td>
                                <td>(405)-456-2858</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Mission Treatment Centers, Inc.</td>
                                <td>5550 South Garnett</td>
                                <td>Tulsa</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>74146</td>
                                <td>(918)-665-2501</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Keetoowah Cherokee Treatment Services</td>
                                <td>2727 East Admiral Place</td>
                                <td>Tulsa</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>74110</td>
                                <td>(918)-835-3017</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Advanced Recovery Services</td>
                                <td>301 SE 59th St</td>
                                <td>Oklahoma City</td>
                                <td>Ok</td>
                                <td>73129</td>
                                <td>(405)-672-3033)</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>




                    </article>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="mainFooter">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2013 <a href="http://OKATOD.org">OKATOD</a></p>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is CSS:

```
/*
    Theme Name: index Theme HTML5/CSS3 Layout
    Description: Basic HTML5/CSS3 layout built on a responsive framework
    Version: 1.0
    Author URL: Trevor Fitzsimmons
*/

/* ===========================
   ======= Body style ======== 
   =========================== */

body {
        background-image: url('http://www.okatod.org/Images/bg.png'); 
    color: #000305; 
    font-size: 87.5%; /* Base font size: 14px */
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.429;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left; 
    }

.body {
        clear: both; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 70%;
}

/* ===========================
   ========= Headings ======== 
   =========================== */
h2 {font-size: 1.571em} /* 22px */
h3 {font-size: 1.429em} /* 20px */
h4 {font-size: 1.286em} /* 18px */
h5 {font-size: 1.143em} /* 16px */
h6 {font-size: 1em}     /* 14px */

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

/* ===========================
   ======= Anchor style ====== 
   =========================== */
a {
    outline: 0;
    }

a img {
    border: 0px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CF5C3F;
    padding: 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ===========================
   ===== Main Navigation ===== 
   =========================== */

.mainHeader nav {
    background: #666;
    font-size: 1.143em;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
    float: left; 
    display: inline; 
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    background: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.mainHeader nav li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader img {
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;%;
    margin: 3% 0; 
}

/* ===========================
   ======= Content Area ====== 
   =========================== */

.mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;         
}

.topcontent {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 3% 5%;         
    text-align: center;
}

.topcontent header {
    margin-top: -20px; 
}

.locationsTable{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableHeadings {
    margin-right: 5px; 
}

.locationsTable th {
    margin-right: 5px; 
}

.locationsTable td {
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
    border: 2px solid #444;
}

.bottomcontent {
    background-color: #FFF; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 3% 5%;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
}

.post-info {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 85%;
}

/* ===========================
   ======== Sidebar ========== 
   =========================== */

.top-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #FFF; 
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.middle-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #FFF; 
    padding: 2% 3%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.bottom-sidebar {
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #FFF; 
    padding: 2% 3%;
}

/* ===========================
   ========= Footer ========== 
   =========================== */

.mainFooter {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    color: #FFF;    
}

.mainFooter p {
    width: 91%;
    margin: 2% auto;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Media Queries ====== 
   =========================== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 780px)
{
    .body {
        clear: both; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 90%;
    }

    .mainHeader nav {
        background: #666;
        font-size: 1.143em;
        height: 160px;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .mainHeader nav ul {
        list-style: none; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .mainHeader nav li {
        margin-left: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
        color: #FFF;
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .mainHeader nav a:active,
    .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
        background: #CF5C3F;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .mainHeader nav li a {
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .mainHeader img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 3%;
    }

    .mainContent {
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .topcontent {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        padding: 2% 5%;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
    }

    .bottomcontent {
        background-color: #FFF; 
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        padding: 2% 5%;
    }

    .content {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    }   

    .post-info {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 0;       
    }

    .top-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .middle-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 0;   
    }

    .middle-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .bottom-sidebar {
        width: 86%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        background-color: #FFF; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        margin-left: 0%;
        padding: 0 7%;
        margin-bottom: 1%;
    }

    .bottom-sidebar p {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .mainFooter {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 2% 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        background-color: #666;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        color: #FFF;    
    }

    .mainFooter p {
        width: 86%;
        margin: 2% auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8" />` should be `<meta charset="utf-8">` (except for XHTML)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that this made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it's really tricky manage "table data" and responsive-design, what happen here is that your words can't break in more lines and that's why the table exploit. A solution not beautifull but it's a solution is to make some more changes in properties with media queries i include this

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 480px)
    {
        .locationsTable tr td{
            word-break:break-all;
            line-height:20px;
            font-size:70%;
    }
```

So you can try this here http://jsfiddle.net/C2wP6/

I include some things:

- Font-size you can reduce it.
- Line-height you also can reduce it to gain more space.
- Word-break forces the word to break in any part (not a really good solution but is the only one i see)

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work. I had looked at word-break in a tutorial and thought earlier it could work but this is the first time I have tried it. Thanks tho!

Comment: WORD-wrap doesn't work beacuse it breaks in lines the text by the white spaces. Word-break breaks the word in any part... Have you checked the jsfiddle that i post? It works fine when you resize

Comment: Maybe you can paste your code in jsfiddle then i can check what are you missing

Comment: When I clicked on the link I saw the code you had posted. So I just copied and pasted the css code into my editor, and it works fine. Did you just add the above media query? This is all that I see that has changed. I really appreciate the help, not sure why it didn't work when I tried it the first time, I probably mistyped something.

Comment: Yes that's all i changed in the css i'm glad that this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A `<table>` has a defined minimum width. In your case words like Administration, Northeast and  Bartlesville constitute a specific width. Those column width cannot be reduced more than that.
Overall `min-width` of your `<table>` is more than 480px.

There is an option to break them to. In a screen less than 480px, you assign a width for each column and make it fit below 480px. Then break words which has width more than the assigned value. For eg. Admin-istrator. This will display as

```
Admin-
istrator
```

thus reducing total width of the `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with tables and responsive design, it might be worth considering reflowing your data.

An example of this can be seen on:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-reflow/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm trying to stick with basic css3 and html5 since this is a basic website. I will consider this if it is a last resort. I thank you for helping!